# HVAC contactor receives 27VAC on both control terminals, and does not close

Tags: hvac

We have a heat pump condenser unit in Florida here. It is a heat pump with "auxiliary/emergency heating". The heat pump mode is not working.

We have made some good progress so far.

When we turn the heat on and press in the contactor with a screwdriver, the condenser unit starts up (fan and compressor) and the air coming out of the vents in the house starts to be noticeably warmer than before. This means the heat pump physically works and the refrigerant might even be fine. Actually this also works on the cool setting, so this is clearly a heat pump and it clearly works.

When we measure the poles on the contactor, for the Load terminals they all check out, but this is a given because physically pushing in the solenoid makes it run and the whole system works.

The control terminals is where it gets interesting. When the thermometer is set to heat these terminals BOTH measure 27VAC against ground. We measured between the control terminals on the contactor when the thermostat is set to heating or cooling or off, and in no situation could we measure anything ACROSS these terminals. This is consistent with the inability of the contactor to close. The question is what might the problem be with the wiring or the control board (on the condenser unit)?

We also are wondering if it makes sense to try as a test for whether the contactor needs to be replaced, is to put one terminal of the contactor against ground, so the 27VAC drains into ground. I am worried about whether this would damage anything (maybe the transformer?). If not, it should be a quick way to see if the contactor is broken or not because it should actuate then.

[image]

Comment: What make and model are the indoor unit and condenser in question?

Comment: I'll update the OP

Comment: It is some Rheem stuff. Will look it up tomorrow.

Comment: A good, clear, focused close-up pic of the control board so that people can read the labels on it might help, too.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about voltage to "ground".  Disconnect the yellow and brown wires from the contactor, make the thermostat call for heating or cooling and then check the voltage between yellow and brown.  That should go from zero volts to 24v.  Worrying about ground (what ground are you even using?) or what the voltage is when connected to the coil could be confusing the situation.

Comment: My dad brought in somebody who knows this stuff and he got it up and running. He tied the left side of the contactor to ground and it worked. He said that the control board behaves weird so we have a replacement on order. 